# Guardar Imagen en sql server desde vb asp

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

buenas quisiera que me ayuden quisiera guardar la imagen en mi base de datos sql server  para eso estoy realizando programacion 3 capas en visual basic asp 
Capa Datos:

```
Public Class D_Atencion
#Region "Declarar Variables"
    Dim CadCnx As New D_Conexion
    Dim Cnx As SqlConnection
    Dim Cmd As SqlCommand
    Dim da As SqlDataAdapter
    Dim dt As DataTable
#End Region
#Region "Incidencias del Usuario"
    Public Function Obtener_Informa_Atencion(ByVal ivOpt As Integer, ByVal svBuscar As String) As DataSet
        Try
            Return SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(CadCnx.CnxWebInci, "PE_Ate_InformacionAtencion_New", ivOpt, svBuscar)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw New Exception(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Function
    Public Function Proceso_Atencion(ByVal ivOpt As Integer, ByVal svViaIncidencia As String, ByVal svReportadoPor As String, ByVal svAgencia As String, ByVal svTipoIncidencia As String, ByVal svSubtipoIncidencia As String, ByVal svDerivarA As String, ByVal svDescripcion As String, ByVal svUsuarioRegistro As String) As String
        Dim _bol As String = ""

        Cnx = New SqlConnection
        Cnx.ConnectionString = CadCnx.CnxWebInci

        dt = New DataTable
        da = New SqlDataAdapter

        Cmd = New SqlCommand
        Cmd.Connection = Cnx
        Cmd.CommandTimeout = 7000000
        Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        Cmd.CommandText = "PE_Ate_ProcesosAtencion_New"


        Cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Opt", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = ivOpt
        Cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ViaIncidencia", SqlDbType.VarChar, 250)).Value = UCase(svViaIncidencia)
        Cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ReportadoPor", SqlDbType.VarChar, 250)).Value = UCase(svReportadoPor)
        Cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Agencia", SqlDbType.VarChar, 250)).Value = UCase(svAgencia)
        Cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@TipoIncidencia", SqlDbType.VarChar, 250)).Value = UCase(svTipoIncidencia)
        Cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@SubtipoIncidencia", SqlDbType.VarChar, 250)).Value = UCase(svSubtipoIncidencia)
        Cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@DerivarA", SqlDbType.VarChar, 150)).Value = UCase(svDerivarA)
        Cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Descripcion", SqlDbType.Text)).Value = UCase(svDescripcion)
        Cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@UsuarioRegistro", SqlDbType.VarChar, 250)).Value = UCase(svUsuarioRegistro)



        Try
            dt.Clear()
            dt.Reset()

            If Cnx.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then Cnx.Open()

            Dim i As Integer = Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
            Cnx.Close()

            If ivOpt = 2 Then
                _bol = If(i > 0, "Incidencia ha sido Atendida...!", "Proceso no pudo llegar a culminarse...!")

            End If

            If ivOpt = 3 Then
                _bol = If(i > 0, "Atención de la Incidencia ha sido Desistida...!", "Proceso no pudo llegar a culminarse...!")
            End If

            If ivOpt = 10 Then
                _bol = If(i > 0, "Atención de la Incidencia ha sido Derivada...!", "Proceso no pudo llegar a culminarse...!")
            End If

            Return _bol
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw New Exception(ex.Message)
            Return False
        End Try
    End Function
    Public Function Proceso_Atencion_1(ByVal ivOpt As Integer, ByVal svViaIncidencia As String, ByVal svReportadoPor As String, ByVal svAgencia As String, ByVal svTipoIncidencia As String, ByVal svSubtipoIncidencia As String, ByVal svDerivarA As String, ByVal svDescripcion As String, ByVal svImagen As String, ByVal svUsuarioRegistro As String) As DataSet
        Try
            Return SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(CadCnx.CnxWebInci, "PE_Ate_ProcesosAtencion_New", ivOpt, UCase(svViaIncidencia), UCase(svReportadoPor), UCase(svAgencia), UCase(svTipoIncidencia), UCase(svSubtipoIncidencia), UCase(svDerivarA), UCase(svDescripcion), UCase(svImagen), UCase(svUsuarioRegistro))
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw New Exception(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Function
#End Region
End Class
```

Capa Negocio:

```
Public Function Proceso_Atencion_1(ByVal ivOpt As Integer, ByVal svViaIncidencia As String, ByVal svReportadoPor As String, ByVal svAgencia As String, ByVal svTipoIncidencia As String, ByVal svSubtipoIncidencia As String, ByVal svDerivarA As String, ByVal svDescripcion As String, ByVal svImagen As String, ByVal svUsuarioRegistro As String) As DataSet
        Try
            Return vD_Atencion.Proceso_Atencion_1(ivOpt, UCase(svViaIncidencia), UCase(svReportadoPor), UCase(svAgencia), UCase(svTipoIncidencia), UCase(svSubtipoIncidencia), UCase(svDerivarA), UCase(svDescripcion), UCase(svImagen), UCase(svUsuarioRegistro))
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw New Exception(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Function
```

Cada Presentacion:

```
 Protected Sub BtnRegistrar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnRegistrar.Click
        Try
            If Not Validar_Registro() Then Exit Sub

            dt = New DataTable
            vB_Atencion = New B_Atencion

            dt = vB_Atencion.Proceso_Atencion_1(1, UCase(CboViaIncidencia.Text.Trim), UCase(TxtUsuario.Text.Trim), UCase(TxtOficina.Text.Trim), UCase(CboTipoIncidencia.Text.Trim), UCase(CboSubTipoAtencion.Text.Trim), IIf(CboDerivar.SelectedIndex = 0, "0", UCase(CboDerivar.Text)), UCase(TxtDescripcion.Text.Trim), UCase(ImagenFile.FileUpload), Session(0)).Tables(0)

            TxtTicket.Text = dt.Rows(0)("NroTicket")

            dt.Dispose()

            Mensaje("Incidencia se registro correctamente...!", "Aviso del Sistema")


            Call Deshabilitar()

            TxtDescripcion.Enabled = False
            BtnRegistrar.Enabled = False

            'If CboDerivar.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
            '    TxtSolucion.Enabled = True
            '    TxtSolucion.Text = ""
            '    TxtSolucion.Focus()
            '    BtnCulminar.Enabled = True
            'End If
            'If CboDerivar.SelectedIndex  0 Then
            '    TxtSolucion.Enabled = False
            '    TxtSolucion.Text = ""
            '    BtnCulminar.Enabled = False
            'End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            Mensaje(Err.Description, "Aviso del Sistema")
            Exit Try
        End Try
    End Sub
```

T-0001

```
                </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
           <th class="auto-style1">
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text="Nombre de Usuario : "></asp:Label>
           </th>
           <td class="auto-style2">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TxtUsuario" runat="server" placeholder="Nombre de Usuario" style="width:90%" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
           </td>
           <th class="auto-style1">
                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text="Nombre de Agencia  :"></asp:Label>
           </th>
           <td class="auto-style2">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TxtOficina" runat="server" placeholder="Nombre de Usuario" style="width:90%" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
           </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <th style="width:15%" >
                <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text="Tipo de Incidente : "></asp:Label>
           </th>
           <td  style="width:35%">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="CboTipoIncidencia" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="8pt" style="width:90%"></asp:DropDownList>
           </td>
           <th  style="width:15%">
                <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text="SubTipo de Incidente  :"></asp:Label>
           </th>
           <td  style="width:35%">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="CboSubTipoAtencion" runat="server" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="8pt" style="width:90%" Enabled="False"></asp:DropDownList>
           </td>
        </tr>
          <tr>
           <th style="width:15%" >
                <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text="Derivar Incidencia  A:"></asp:Label>

           </th>
           <td  style="width:35%">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="CboDerivar" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="8pt" style="width:90%" Enabled="False"></asp:DropDownList>
           </td>
           <th  style="width:15%">
                &nbsp;</th>
           <td  style="width:35%">
                &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
             <th>
                  <asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text="Subir Archivo:"></asp:Label>
             </th>
             **<td>
                 <input type="file" id="ImagenFile" runat="server"/>
             </td>**
         </tr>

        <tr>
            <th colspan="4">
                <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text="Ingresar Detalladamente la incidencia por favor, considerar que mínimo debe de ingresar 20 caracteres:"></asp:Label>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" style="text-align:center">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TxtDescripcion" runat="server" style="width: 98%; height:120px" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>

                <br />
                <br />
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ASP != ASP.net MVC

Comment: Muchas gracias por la correccion

Comment: de nada bro :D Agrega los demás métodos: vD_Atencion.Proceso_Atencion_1 para tener en cuenta cómo manejas tus sentencias en la BD. saludos :D

Comment: ya lo subi muchas gracias por las recomendaciones espero que me ayuden

Comment: cómo planeas almacenar la imagen? dentro de la base de datos o como archivo en una carpeta llamada uploads (o algo así) ?

Comment: seria guardar en la base de datos la ruta de la imagen para luego mostrarla pero lo que no me sale es en el registro

Comment: coloca varios breakpoints y mira dónde te lanza un error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acuerdo al título de la pregunta, aquí la respuesta :D

Nombre de la tabla: `tblFiles`

```
| Campo       | Detalle                            |
|-------------|------------------------------------|
| id          | Identification Number              |
| Name        | Nombre del archivo                 |
| ContentType | Tipo de contenido para el archivo  |
| Data        | Archivo guardado como Binary Data  |
```

Cadena de conexión

```
<connectionStrings>

<add name="conString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;database=dbFiles; Integrated Security=true"/>

</connectionStrings >
```

Un archivo.aspx

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />

<asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="btnUpload_Click" />    
<br />    
<asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Text="" Font-Names = "Arial"></asp:Label>
```

Creamos el método

```
Public Function InsertUpdateData(ByVal cmd As SqlCommand) As Boolean

    Dim strConnString As String = System.Configuration.    
    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("conString").ConnectionString    
    Dim con As New SqlConnection(strConnString)    
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text    
    cmd.Connection = con

    Try

      con.Open()    
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()    
      Return True

    Catch ex As Exception

      Response.Write(ex.Message)    
      Return False

    Finally

      con.Close()    
      con.Dispose()

    End Try

End Function
```

En el evento click del botón btnUpload:

```
Protected Sub btnUpload_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

  'Leemos el archivo y lo convertimos a un Byte Array'

  Dim filePath As String = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName    
  Dim filename As String = Path.GetFileName(filePath)    
  Dim ext As String = Path.GetExtension(filename)    
  Dim contenttype As String = String.Empty     

  'Definimos el tipo de contenido basado en la extension'

  Select Case ext

    Case ".doc"    
      contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-word"    
      Exit Select

    Case ".docx"    
      contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-word"    
      Exit Select

    Case ".xls"    
      contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-excel"    
      Exit Select

    Case ".xlsx"    
      contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-excel"    
      Exit Select

    Case ".jpg"    
      contenttype = "image/jpg"    
      Exit Select

    Case ".png"    
      contenttype = "image/png"    
      Exit Select

    Case ".gif"    
      contenttype = "image/gif"    
      Exit Select

    Case ".pdf"    
      contenttype = "application/pdf"    
      Exit Select

    End Select

    If contenttype <> String.Empty Then    
      Dim fs As Stream = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream    
      Dim br As New BinaryReader(fs)    
      Dim bytes As Byte() = br.ReadBytes(fs.Length)    

      'Insertamos en la base de datos'

       Dim strQuery As String = "insert into tblFiles" _    
       & "(Name, ContentType, Data)" _    
       & " values (@Name, @ContentType, @Data)"    
       Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(strQuery)    
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = filename    
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@ContentType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value _    
       = contenttype    
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@Data", SqlDbType.Binary).Value = bytes 

       InsertUpdateData(cmd)    

       lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green    
       lblMessage.Text = "Archivo subido con éxito!"    
     Else    
       lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red    
       lblMessage.Text = "Formato del archivo no reconocido." _    
       & " Se aceptan sólo formato de Imágenes/Word/PDF/Excel"    
     End If    
  End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrias crear una carpeta en tu proyecto llamada **Imagenes** y ahí almacenas las imagenes que quieras, en la Base de Datos almacenas unicamente la **Ruta** y **Nombre** de cada imagen.

```
   If FileUpload1.HasFile = True Then
                        If FileUpload1.PostedFile IsNot Nothing Then 'Validar que se seleccione un archivo
                            Dim Nombre As String = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName) 'Definir el Nombre del archivo Seleccionado
                            FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Imagenes/" & Nombre)) 'Guardar Imagen en carpeta Imagenes con el nombre asignado anteriormente 
                            Dim con As New SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("TuConexion").ConnectionString) 'Conexion a la DB
                            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("insert into archivos (ruta_archivo,NOMBRE) values(@ruta,@NOMBRE)") 'Insert a la Tabla                        
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ruta", "~/Archivos/Imagenes/" & Nombre) 'Guardar ruta y nombre de la imagen                         
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NOMBRE", Nombre)'Guardar nombre de la Imagen                         
                            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                            cmd.Connection = con
                            Try
                                con.Open()
                                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                            Catch ex As Exception
                                Response.Write(ex.Message)
                            Finally
                                con.Close()
                                con.Dispose()
                            End Try
                        End If
                    End If
```